# QT - slot preemption / interrupt

Tags: c++, qt5

I'm trying to write an app for testing ST board via serial port and I'm currently facing the following issue. (The code below is just a simplification of a problem.)

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , m_button(new QPushButton(this))
    , m_timer(new QTimer(this))
{
    m_timer->setSingleShot(true);
    connect(m_button, &QPushButton::released, this, &Widget::RunTest);
    connect(m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Widget::OnTimeout);
}

void Widget::RunTest()
{
    qDebug() << "Start test";

    m_timer->start(1000);
    while (m_timeout != true);

    qDebug() << "Start end";
}

void Widget::OnTimeout()
{
    qDebug() << "Timeout";
    m_timeout = true;
}
```

I want to have a seprate class for gathering and running tests. The tests are triggered by clicking on a button. Some tests will have to send data via serial port and wait for the reply. I would like to be able to implement a timeout feature (if board doesn't reply then finish test with failure). However I the app is waiting for the m_timeout flag indefinitely. So my question is: Is there any signal/slot mechanism similar to interrupt preemption? If no how sush problems are solved in Qt? Shall I create seprate QTimer object and run it in separate thread?

Comment: Get rid of the `while (m_timeout != true);` the rest looks fine.

Comment: To add to the comment of @drescherjm, in general try to avoid using `while` as much as possible. If you have to wait for something, use signals ans slots. Said otherwise, don't wait for something to happen. React to events instead.

Comment: @drescherjm ;) That was more than an upvote. Thank you for the kind words!

Comment: But the point is that after this while loop I want to do some checks on the received frame.

Comment: Use signals and slots instead of the loop: Related [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#signals) and its base class [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#signals)

Comment: I don't have any problems with communication via serial port. This is done in separate thread and it works perfectly fine. My question is: Is there any mechanism to make the above code work? Meaning that the RunTest slot will be preempted by a OnTimeout slot?

Comment: Again you need to get rid of the while loop. If the work is done with the otther thread use signals and slots for that other thread to communicate with the Widget

Comment: One other suggestion in addition to the above that may help is make the test a class of its own. Derive it from `QObject` so that it can have signals and slots. Put the timer in the test class. When your test class gets a signal from the thread, it can handle whatever operation you wanted to happen after the while loop in some slot. It also can handle the timeout situation in some slot and notify the thread to take action on the timeout. You may want to have multiple test classes depending on your testing procedure.